# ngModel is not binding properly with ng-for

Tags: angular

I have a request that return this JSON array:

```
{
    "questionId": 1,
    "questionContext": "Over the past two weeks, how often have you had little interest or pleasure in doing things?",
    "qReq": true,
    "qAnswerType": 2,
    "answerOptions": [
        {
            "answerId": 1,
            "answerContext": "Between 15-30 Days",
            "aOrdinal": 1,
            "isAnswer": false,
            "ngAnswerField": "Answer1"
        },
        {
            "answerId": 2,
            "answerContext": "Between 30-60 Days",
            "aOrdinal": 2,
            "isAnswer": false,
            "ngAnswerField": "Answer2"
        },
        {
            "answerId": 3,
            "answerContext": "Between 60-90 Days",
            "aOrdinal": 3,
            "isAnswer": false,
            "ngAnswerField": "Answer3"
        }
    ]
}
```

I am populating a form dynamically in my Angular component like the following:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-survey-edit',
  templateUrl: './survey-edit.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./survey-edit.component.css']
})
export class SurveyEditComponent implements OnInit {
  RadioModel: any = {};
  questionContext = '';
  answerOptions: any;
  ngOnInit() {
     this.surveyEditService.GetQADetail(this.currentQuestionOrdinal, this.surveyId).subscribe(question => {
        if (question) {
          console.log(question);
          this.questionContext = question.questionContext;
          this.answerOptions = question.answerOptions;
        }
      }, error => {
        // Server error
        this.alertify.error(error);
      });
   }
}
```

The data is coming as expected when I do console.log, but the problem is with creating this form dynamically in the html via `ng-for`

Here is my html template:

```
<form
              novalidate
              (ngSubmit)="SaveAnswer(RadioButtonForm)"
              #RadioButtonForm="ngForm"
              autocomplete="off">
                <fieldset>
                  <div class="form-group row">
                    <label class="col-md-2 col-form-label">Question {{currentQuestionOrdinal}}</label>
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                      <pre>{{ questionContext }}</pre>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="custom-control custom-radio" *ngFor="let answerOption of answerOptions">
                          <input
                            type="radio"
                            id="customRadio{{answerOption.aOrdinal}}"
                            name="RadioModel.customRadio"
                            class="custom-control-input"
                            checked="{{answerOption.isAnswer}}"
                            [(ngModel)]="answerOption.isAnswer">
                          <label class="custom-control-label" for="customRadio{{answerOption.aOrdinal}}">{{answerOption.answerContext}}</label>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                   <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                      <button class="btn btn-secondary mr-3"
                              type="submit"
                              [disabled]="!RadioButtonForm.valid">
                        Previous
                      </button>
                      <button class="btn btn-secondary"
                              type="submit"
                              [disabled]="!RadioButtonForm.valid">
                        Next
                      </button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                 </fieldset>

        </form>
```

I can't seem to understand why ngModel or checked property are not working. In fact the page is showing up but The problem is the form (radio buttons) are acting weird meaning that when you select one radio button, it will not let you select another one.. the binding for some reason is not done properly.

Comment: I think also `ngModel` has to be bound to a boolean value

Comment: @MedaiP90, you mean through [ngClass]

Comment: This form should populate radio buttons and if the user left out the question without selecting one of the radio buttons then it should not let the user continue

Comment: One moment... What `RadioModel.answerOption.ngAnswerField` that value is?

Comment: RadioModel is defined in the component as type any..
answerOption.ngAnswerField is the actual value returned

Comment: In your ngModel you assign it via {{ }} which is error. it should only be [(ngModel)]="value"

Comment: I think this is wrong.. but still removing RadioModel still did not fix the issue

Comment: @dAxx_ is right, plus i think ngModel for a radio button wants a boolean value like `answerOption.isAnswer`

Comment: If its not only the {{}} problem, you better attach the error logs since there might be more templates errors which can be easily found in the errors.

Comment: hmm.. so you are suggesting to do something like this [(ngModel)]=answerOption.isAnswer

Comment: And input is not a self closing tag (you forgot `/>`)

Comment: @Riad yes, tht's what i'm suggesting

Comment: I can tell you that if I removed both
#{{answerOption.ngAnswerField}}="ngModel"
                            [(ngModel)]="{{RadioModel.answerOption.ngAnswerField}}" then it will work.. but there is no data binding obviously

Comment: I tried [(ngModel)]="{{answerOption.isAnswer}}" and it did not work.. still template error

Comment: `[(ngModel)]="answerOption.isAnswer"`

Comment: @MedaiP90 your solution worked but now the radio buttons are acting weird.. meaning that I can switch selection from one to another for some reaons. I will update the code above to see the changes.. also I am not getting any console error to attach it here

Comment: thats because the ngModel is bound bidirectionally (and this is its usage), try to make the radios non-clickable if you don't want to modify values

Comment: @dAxx_ you are right.. but still the form is acting weird

Comment: @MedaiP90 how can I do that? I know that [(ngModel)] is a 2-way binding but I really care about what the user selects

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209100/discussion-between-medaip90-and-riad).

Comment: I would suggest to remove the `[(ngModel)]` and try to use `Reactive forms` and bind the `<input>` with `formControlName`. See here: https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms @Riad

Comment: @TheodoreTsg does that mean it can't be done with ngModel?

Comment: @Riad yes it can be done with ngModel but I prefer to use `Reactive forms` to bind the inputs inside my form with typescript.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was a little bit tricky for me. Basically, the property [value] has to match the value for the [(ngModel)] in order to select the appropriate value like the following:

```
<div class="custom-control custom-radio" *ngFor="let answerOption of answerOptions">
  <input
    type="radio"
    id="{{answerOption.ngAnswerId}}"
    name="customRadio"
    class="custom-control-input"
    [value]="answerOption.answerContext"
    (change)="onItemChange(answerOption)"
    [checked]="answerOption.isAnswer"
    ([ngModel])="answerOption.ngAnswerField">
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="{{answerOption.ngAnswerId}}">{{answerOption.answerContext}}</label>
</div>
```

I had to update my response JSON to be like the following:

```
"answerOptions": [
        {
            "answerId": 1,
            "answerContext": "Between 15-30 Days",
            "aOrdinal": 1,
            "isAnswer": false,
            "ngAnswerId": "Answer1",
            "ngAnswerField": "",
            "qaId": 1
        },
        {
            "answerId": 2,
            "answerContext": "Between 30-60 Days",
            "aOrdinal": 2,
            "isAnswer": true,
            "ngAnswerId": "Answer2",
            "ngAnswerField": "Between 30-60 Days",
            "qaId": 2
        },
        {
            "answerId": 3,
            "answerContext": "Between 60-90 Days",
            "aOrdinal": 3,
            "isAnswer": false,
            "ngAnswerId": "Answer3",
            "ngAnswerField": "",
            "qaId": 3
        }
    ]
```

Any feedback or note is appreciated.